# Two custom bindings of the same type on a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        alert(value);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({
    firstValue: ko.observable(true),
    secondValue: ko.observable(false)
});

<input data-bind="myBinding: firstValue, myBinding: secondValue"/>
```

Running this yields only one alert box with "false". Is there a setting that I can utilize to get the expected behavior, or are my options limited to doing this:

```
var temp = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        alert(value);
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = temp;
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding2 = temp;

ko.applyBindings({
    firstValue: ko.observable(true),
    secondValue: ko.observable(false)
});

<input data-bind="myBinding: firstValue, myBinding2: secondValue"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use two of the same bindings on the same element, as they are keyed internally.

You would need to either create a binding that accepts both values or an array of values like:

`data-bind="myBinding: [firstValue, secondValue]"`

Then operator on each one.

Otherwise, you could do what you are suggesting and create more than one binding that points to the same function.